# ¿Cómo ordenar alfabéticamente una colección de varios atributos sin tener en cuenta mayúsculas y minúsculas?

Tags: java, ordenamiento

Mi código ahora mismo ordena alfabéticamente pero teniendo en cuenta por lo que he visto el valor UNICODE de las letras, por ello ordena primero las mayúsculas y después las minúsculas. Pongo aquí mi código del método para ordenarlo, puesto que también ordena por año de compra. La funcion del return es otra auxiliar simplemente para devolverlo con un cierto formato que nos han especificado.

```
public String[][] ordenarFabricanteAnio() {
    //String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER (puede ser usado)
    Collections.sort(figuras, Comparator.comparing(Figura :: getFabricante).thenComparing(Figura :: getAnio));

    return devolverFigurasMatriz();
}
```

Lo que busco es que el método ordene alfabéticamente sin tener en cuenta este orden por ejemplo ABab, sino que fuese AaBb o aAbB.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Para ordenar sin tener en cuenta la distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, puedes usar el método "compareToIgnoreCase"  https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_comparetoignorecase.asp para darte una mejor ayuda, podrías adjuntar más código

Comment: Me parece chistoso porque es que tienes la respuesta en un comentario de tu propio código. Usa `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` como segundo argumento del comparing de fabricante. `Collections.sort(figuras, Comparator.comparing(Figura::getFabricante,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) .thenComparing(Figura::getAnio));`